# <img> height equals to its width inside a div

Tags: html, css

First of all, I'm not really good with CSS but I'm trying to make the `<img>` height equals the width of it using only CSS.
I'm also using **bootstrap** as shown below, so the width of each column is responsive.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';

.album .album_photo .photo_link img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="album">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="album_photo">
      <a href="#" class="photo_link">
        <img src="someurl" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="album_photo">
      <a href="#" class="photo_link">
        <img src="someurl" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it **looks** like right now:
[image]

and this is what I'm trying to **achieve**:
[image]

Comment: please make a fiddle or codepen. I will fix it for you. I need to know about your current classes. the code you posted is not enough

Comment: @Mojtaba sorry I updated my question. P.S. you same name as mine :)

Comment: no problem. the main point is you found your answer P.S. you are a lucky guy ;)

Comment: @Mojtaba seems like i didnt find the answer

Comment: Well, I edited Joseph's answer. It should be what you want now

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this pen, you'll know how to do that using *padding-bottom* trick:
[Code pen](http://codepen.io/lampt2509/pen/QKbgrR)

```
.album_photo {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not help with the aspect ratio though

Answer (score 2):

try this

```css
img{
aspect-ratio:1;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Answer (score 1):

Consider using image as background in conjunction with [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: I have this in mind but it would be better if I could do it with <img> tag

Answer (score 1):

I like this method.  It makes the content of the column (in this case `.album_photo`) `position: relative`, sets the inner wrapper of the element ('.photo_link img') `position: absolute;` with a height of `100%`.  To keep the shape of the column, you use a pseudo-element that has a `padding-top: 100%`.  The reason why this works is because percentage based padding is always relative to the width of the element.  Thus with a padding of `100%`, it will always be just as tall as it is wide.  You can use the same method to create ratio based container sizes too (e.g. 3:1 ratio for slideshows having absolutely positioned slides).  It's a neat trick.

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);

.album_photo {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo_link img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.album_photo:after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="album">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="album_photo">
        <a href="#" class="photo_link"><img src="//placehold.it/300x200" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="album_photo">
        <a href="#" class="photo_link"><img src="//placehold.it/300x200" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="album_photo">
        <a href="#" class="photo_link"><img src="//placehold.it/300x200" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="album_photo">
        <a href="#" class="photo_link"><img src="//placehold.it/300x200" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sayed Awesome! Glad I could help.

Comment: Looks like this does not work if different-orientation images are mixed while `background-size: cover` would work regardless of image orientation.

Comment: @MaratTanalin thats right! Joseph is there a solution or should I just do the background way?!

Comment: @sayed It's easily adapted to work with portrait by switching the `height` to `width` in `.photo_link img` and using `top:50%`, `left:0`, and `transform: translateY(-50%)` instead, but there's no way that I know of with this method to accommodate both portrait and landscape images without using a logical language (not CSS) to first check the orientation. If you want that kind of flexibility, you'll have to drop the semantic advantages of an `img` tag and hard code your image links as the background image inline style.  Really that depends on your application's business logic at that point.

Comment: @sayed I take that back... It might be possible.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @sayed nope. nevermind.  It doesn't scale with the approach I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the images in any way, by simply applying a width & height. For example, You can say

```
.full-width-height { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

You can also use min-width, max-width, min-height and max-height.

However, you will run into aspect ratio issues with this.

You have two options that will keep aspect ratios in check using CSS and

```
.auto-width { width: auto; height: xxx; } 
.auto-height { width: xxx; height: auto; }
```

Bootstrap provides a responsive class you can use as well. The class is **img-responsive** which you can read about [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). This class is often used with **center-block** helper class.

Answer (score -1):

you want your "`album_photo`" class to have a width and height of 100%, because those will fill the space in the parent element which has a class of "`col-xs-3`"

CSS:

```
  .album_photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

set margin and padding to 0 and you will see that the img fits nicely in the parent element.